# c# automapper lookup value from source model

Tags: c#, json, linq, automapper

I have a model which has a generic properties property looking something like this:

```
public class GenericProperty 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

Next to that I have a object that has a list with GenericProperties like this:

```
public class GenericEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<GenericProperty> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

Now im calling a API that deserialize the json to the model above. Next i want to use AutoMapper to construct an actual good looking model so i did the following:

```
Mapper.Initialize(x =>
{
x.CreateMap<GenericEntity, MyModel>()
    .ForMember(d => d.ManagerId, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Properties.Where(n => n.Name == "ManagerId" ).Select(v => v.Value)))
});
```

Problem is that this returns the property type and not the actual value:
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereListIterator`1[MyProject.Models.GenericProperty]

How can i lookup the value of within the model?

Comment: `Where()` is returning an `IEnumerable` of **all** the properties with the name "ManagerId". You want to use `Single()` to return one value - if you can guarantee it's always present - otherwise `SingleOrDefault()` and handle the null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `Where` you are selecting all the properties with the name ManagerId. You should instead use `Single` like in this unit test:

```
public class TestClass
{
    [Test]
    public void TestMapper()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.CreateMap<GenericEntity, MyModel>()
                .ForMember(d => d.ManagerId,
                           o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Properties.Single(n => n.Name == "ManagerId").Value));
        });

        var ge = new GenericEntity
        {
            Properties = new List<GenericProperty>
            {
                new GenericProperty {Name = "ManagerId", Value = "Great"}
            }
        };

        var myModel = Mapper.Map<MyModel>(ge);

        Assert.AreEqual("Great", myModel.ManagerId);
    }
}
```

If you can not guarantee that there will be a property with the name ManagerId, you should use `SingleOrDefault`, and handle the null case.

IMHO, you should limit this kind of AutoMapper configurations to simple cases, since it quickly gets difficult to debug and maintain.

For more complex mappings like this one, I would recommend you to make an explicit mapping method instead, which you can call like an extension method. Another option worth considering if you want to use Automapper are [Custom value resolvers](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers).

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. I now realized what I did wrong so thats a good thing.
Now i have another thing to figure out because apparently the api im consuming sometimes returns a string and sometimes an json object in the GenericProperty.Value.
With Automapper i now need to check if its an object or string, if its an object it should return the value of that object(the object is not more then just an object with a value property). Any change you might have the answer on that one as well?

Comment: As I said, that's a lot of logic, too much for this kind of mapping configuration. I recommend you to put it in a dedicated mapping method, or in an Automapper Custom value resolver

Comment: Thanks, i got it to work using "CreateMap<object, string>().ConvertUsing(MappingFunction)"